# Django-Oscar - Forking nested applications

Tags: django, django-settings, django-oscar

I'm having trouble forking Django-oscar apps that are a part of a sub-set of other Django-oscar apps. For the documentation/tutorial I am following along with, view [here](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/topics/customisation.html#fork-oscar-app).

I have gone though and successfully forked the applications that aren't nested in others and updated my installed apps accordingly. Heres a subset of the apps to demonstrate the general pattern of the nested applications

```
'dashboard_folder.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports.apps.ReportsDashboardConfig',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.offers.apps.OffersDashboardConfig',
```

However, the docs (linked above) do not clearly outline how to call the nested applications. I thought they might be forked automatically with their "parents" however, a simple test (code below) proved other-wise:

If I change `'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports.apps.ReportsDashboardConfig',` to
`dashboard_folder.dashboard.reports.apps.ReportsDashboardConfig',`

I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dashboard_folder.dashboard.reports'`

I figured id try a few 'educated' guesses as to how to call the nested apps to fork them however all of the following unfortunately failed:

```
manage.py oscar_fork_app offers offers_folder
CommandError: There is no app with the label 'offers'

manage.py oscar_fork_app dashboard.offers offers_folder
CommandError: There is no app with the label 'dashboard.offers'

manage.py oscar_fork_app ReportsDashboard ReportsDashboard_folder
CommandError: There is no app with the label 'ReportsDashboard'

manage.py oscar_fork_app reportsdashboard ReportsDashboard_folder
CommandError: There is no app with the label 'reportsdashboard'

manage.py oscar_fork_app dashboard/reportsdashboard ReportsDashboard_folder
CommandError: There is no app with the label 'dashboard/reportsdashboard'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm a couple more trys away from just emailing Django-oscar for help but maybe this question will be of help to someone else in the future!

EDIT:

Here is my dashboard app config for reference:

```
import oscar.apps.dashboard.apps as apps

class DashboardConfig(apps.DashboardConfig):
    name = 'dashboard_folder.dashboard'
```

the same general pattern is followed for all other Oscar forked applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that the documentation on this isn't very clear. The first argument to `oscar_fork_app` is the *app label* for the app you want to fork. In the case of top level apps this is something like `offer` or `catalogue`, but for nested apps you need to check the `apps.py` for that app to see the label.

If you take `oscar.apps.dashboard.reports.apps.ReportsDashboardConfig` for example, then it's app config looks like this:

```
class ReportsDashboardConfig(OscarDashboardConfig):
    label = 'reports_dashboard'    # <--- this is important
```

The `label` is what you need to use to fork the app. So something like:

```
python manage.py oscar_fork_app reports_dashboard path/to/your_forks_directory
```

Note also that the second argument needs to be the path to *the top level of the directory in which you keep all your forked apps*. The children of this directory have to match Oscar's app structure, and nested apps will be forked into the appropriate nested directory inside it.

If you still get a `ModuleNotFoundError` after this, then it is most likely because the app `name` auto-generated by Oscar doesn't quite match your project structure. Check this name to see if it matches a module found within your project, and adjust it if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know how I could view the app config prior to forking the application? To continue with your example of the dashboard config, it forks only with its own config and not that of its "children." Using the pattern you displayed above I could continue to fork each other application however I would like to confirm that I have not missed something crucial along the way.

Comment: to help elaborate on what I meant by "it forks only with its own config" I have added an edit to my original question with my full dashboard app config.

Comment: You can't view the generated app config until the command is run, if that is what you mean. The command will not automatically fork child apps - if you want to fork a child you need to do that explicitly after forking its parent.